# OpenFDA Covid19 Serology Tests DB Created_On/Updated_On Fields?

Tags: openfda, covid19

We are looking to monitor data that is added/changed within the DB on a daily basis.  When looking at the results returned from the OpenFDA Covid19 Serology Tests API, it appears that in the metadata there is reference to when the DB was updated, but there does not appear to be a way to see the records within the DB that were actually updated.

For example...  As of today, there are 4180 results and the DB was updated yesterday.  There does not appear to be a way to identify which records within the database were updated or added as there is no record field for updated_on or created_on - only when the actual test was performed with date_performed.  As this test could have been performed some time before being added to the database, and probably does not correlate to when the test was added or updated within the db, we can't easily see what has changed.

```
{
  "meta": {
    "last_updated": "2020-07-26",
    "terms": "https://open.fda.gov/terms/",
    "results": {
      "skip": 0,
      "total": 4180,
      "limit": 4180
    },
    "license": "https://open.fda.gov/license/",
    "disclaimer": "Do not rely on openFDA to make decisions regarding medical care. While we make every effort to ensure that data is accurate, you should assume all results are unvalidated. We may limit or otherwise restrict your access to the API in line with our Terms of Service."
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "control": "Pass",
      "lot_number": "COV1252003C",
      "igm_agree": "TN",
      "date_performed": "5/8/2020",
      "sample_id": "C0054",
      "iga_result": "NA",
      "igg_truth": "Negative",
      "pan_result": "NA",
      "igg_agree": "TN",
      "group": "HIV+",
      "igg_titer": "0",
      "igm_titer": "0",
      "igg_result": "Negative",
      "manufacturer": "Abacus Pharma International",
      "type": "Plasma",
      "igm_truth": "Negative",
      "igm_igg_agree": "NA",
      "days_from_symptom": "NA",
      "sample_no": "30",
      "antibody_agree": "TN",
      "device": "SARS-CoV-2 IgM/IgG AB Antibody Rapid Test (Immunochromatography)",
      "igm_igg_result": "NA",
      "panel": "Panel 1",
      "antibody_truth": "Negative",
      "pan_titer": "0",
      "iga_agree": "NA",
      "evaluation_id": "maf3257-a001",
      "pan_agree": "NA",
      "igm_result": "Negative"
    },
....
```

As we are looking to see what has changed, it would be nice if each record had something like searchable fields of "created_on" and "updated_on" so specific tests that were added/updated could be monitored instead of having to do a comparison of every record's field to find results that had changed from the previous update.

Are there any plans to add these fields to the database as it would make tracking changes much, much easier for external (and potentially internal) interested parties?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, because the COVID data we receive internally for this dataset do not have the two fields you're looking for, openFDA is unable to provide them. We would recommend that you contact CDRH at FDA directly with your inquiry and see if the two fields could be added to the dataset. Sorry about the inconvenience.